# Generating username from first name and last name in C

Tags: c

I am writing a C program to generate userid's from a given file (`users`). The file has each user's first and last names each line (eg. "John Smith", "Steve Mathews" etc). The following `while` loop reads each line from `users` and prints in the console in all lowercase. In this case, `single_line` holds names in lower case.

```
while(!feof(fp)) {
        fgets(single_line, 80, fp);
        for(int i = 0; single_line[i]; i++){
          single_line[i] = tolower(single_line[i]);
        }
        char f_letter = single_line[0];
        char r_letters[20];
}
```

Now, I want to create a username for each `single_line` with the first letter of the first name and remaining letters of last name. So far, `f_letter` holds the first letter of first name, how can I make `r_letters` hold the remaining letters of last name?

Comment: have you tried using `strtok` on single_line, using the space character as your separator?

Comment: Copy `f_letter` to `r_letters`.  Then copy the last name after it.

Comment: Check the return value of `fgets()` before using `single_line`

Comment: [why `while(!feof(fp))` is wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char first_name[81];
char last_name[81];
char user_name[82];
while(!feof(fp)) {
        if(fscanf(fp, "%80s %80s", first_name,last_name) == 2){

            for(i = 0; i < strlen(first_name); i++){
              first_name[i] = tolower(first_name[i]);
            }
            for(i = 0; i < strlen(last_name); i++){
              last_name[i] = tolower(last_name[i]);
            }

            sprintf(user_name, "%c%s", first_name[0], last_name);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`strtok`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) to extract tokens from strings using a delimiter.

For example, for a line of text read from a file using `fgets` (assuming each line only contains two words, as is your case), you can extract the first and second words as:

```
char *first_name = strtok(single_line, " ");
char *last_name = strtok(NULL, "\n");
```

*newline* character is used as the second delimiter because `fgets` preserves it when reading a line, so it can be used to extract the last token before the newline.

Consider the following function for creating usernames:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void create_usernames(char *filename) {
    char line[80], username[80];
    char *last;
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    // fgets returns a NULL pointer upon EOF or error
    while (fgets(line, 80, fp) != NULL) {
        last = strtok(line, " ");
        last = strtok(NULL, "\n");
        printf("%c%s\n", line[0], last);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

For example, with a file `file.txt` containing names:

```
John Smith
John Diggle
Bruce Wayne
Steve Mathews
```

you would have:

```
create_usernames("file.txt");
JSmith
JDiggle
BWayne
SMathews
```

Answer (score 0):

find the index of the space between the first and last name, say `j`.  the index of the first letter of the last name would be `j+1`.